# not unique cells in cellForItemAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

What is really happening on these lines

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  MenuCollectionViewCell *cell = (MenuCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier
                                                                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

specially on the cell line?

As far as I understand, when I scroll the collection view revealing new cells that were not visible and by consequence hiding cells that were visible, iOS will reuse cells those cells that went out of screen to draw the new ones, right?

The problem is this: if I customize a particular cell based on the indexPath, I will have several repetitions of that customization. For example, if I set one cell's label to red, I will have a lot of cells with red labels as soon as I scroll the collection view and the cell is dequeued and reused.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `[UICollectionViewCell prepareForReuse]` and reset all customizations in the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can either clear them down in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, before configuring the cell for the new indexPath, or if you have a custom subclass of UITableViewCell, override the `prepareForReuse` method and clear it down there.  See the [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse).

**EDIT**
Sorry, you are working with collection view rather than table view, but the same applies.

Answer (score 0):

Override `prepareForReuse` to reset resources,it will be call when cell scroll out of frame

Don't forget call super method